# Sorting tags by name

Tags: taxonomy, tags, sort

I'm displaying a lit of tags when they have a description. I'd like to sort them by name instead of by post quantity. Is there a way to do this?

```
<?php 
    $tags = get_tags();
    if ($tags) {
      foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        if ($tag->description) {
          echo '<dt><a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '><h3>' . $tag->name.'</h3></a></dt><dd style="margin-bottom: 10px;">' . $tag->description . '</dd>';
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the function **wp_tag_cloud**, it has many parameters as described [in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud) and the one to sort the results as you want: `'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC',`.

Comment: How would I pull all teags including those that aren't attached to a post?

Comment: Set the 'number' parameter to 0, it'll pull all the tags. This function retrieves general tags, not the ones attached to a post.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I'm looking to pull absolutely all of the tags.

Comment: Yes it does. This is the code `$args = array('smallest' => 8, 'largest' => 8,'unit' => 'px', 'number' => 0); wp_tag_cloud( $args );` that i used to pull all the tags on this page:  http://regrouped.net/tags-list/

Comment: Wild I wonder what's broken then? The only results I'm getting are from tags that are associated with posts. Not any of the ones that are just listed in the Post Tags and have "0". Every result you have listed on that page is connected to a post. Nice site btw.

Comment: Did you put the function call in the loop or outside?

Comment: Outside, this is on a template page.

Comment: btw, `get_tags()` has the `orderby` parameter which allows to sort by name (which is also the default) http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the above answer is lacking a lot of flexibility. `wp_tag_cloud()` is going to output a whole slew of HTML, and nothing friendly to manipulate in the PHP.

`get_tags()` already has support for `orderby` in the input array, since it's a term query (reference: [the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/))

So here's a sample of how you'd do that, and I'm listing the full options below

```
      $tags = get_tags(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'hide_empty' => false // for development
      ));
```

Big ol' list of all available parameters with their defaults:

```
$args = array(
        'taxonomy'               => null,
        'object_ids'             => null,
        'orderby'                => 'name',
        'order'                  => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'             => true,
        'include'                => array(),
        'exclude'                => array(),
        'exclude_tree'           => array(),
        'number'                 => '',
        'offset'                 => '',
        'fields'                 => 'all',
        'count'                  => false,
        'name'                   => '',
        'slug'                   => '',
        'term_taxonomy_id'       => '',
        'hierarchical'           => true,
        'search'                 => '',
        'name__like'             => '',
        'description__like'      => '',
        'pad_counts'             => false,
        'get'                    => '',
        'child_of'               => 0,
        'parent'                 => '',
        'childless'              => false,
        'cache_domain'           => 'core',
        'update_term_meta_cache' => true,
        'meta_query'             => '',
        'meta_key'               => '',
        'meta_value'             => '',
        'meta_type'              => '',
        'meta_compare'           => '',
);
```